# express-subdomain not resolving any subdomain

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express-subdomain to resolve locally `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com` with 2 different results.

The output however is always the one assigned to `example.com`. I have tested different syntax from various suggestions, but I had no luck.

I have added both addresses to `/etc/hosts`.

This is my code:

```
var subdomain = require("express-subdomain");
var express = require("express");

var router1 = express.Router();
var router2 = express.Router();

// Home page route.
router1.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("this is example.com");
});

// Subdomain route.
router2.get("subdomain", function (req, res) {
  res.send("This is the subdomain.example.com");
});

var app = express();

app.use("/", router1);
app.use(subdomain("/", router2));

app.listen(3000);
```

I have been trying for days but nothing seems to work. How can I render the 2 results?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out (credit to @ixuz07):

I need to change this:

```
router2.get("subdomain", function (req, res) {
  res.send("This is the subdomain.example.com");
});

app.use(subdomain("/", router2));
```

with this:

```
router2.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("This is the subdomain.example.com");
});

app.use(subdomain("subdomain", router2));
```

and swap the order between this 2:

```
app.use("/", router1);
app.use(subdomain("/", router2));
```

so the final code is:

```
var subdomain = require("express-subdomain");
var express = require("express");

var router1 = express.Router();
var router2 = express.Router();

// Home page route.
router1.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("this is example.com");
});

// Subdomain route.
router2.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("This is the subdomain.example.com");
});

var app = express();

app.use(subdomain("subdomain", router2));
app.use("/", router1);

app.listen(3000);
```